# Inner element's positioning being overwritten by parent div's pos

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an div that sticks to the bottom of a page. Inside that div, a button pops up (after 2 seconds) that the user can click to close the housing div.

The housing div has a `fixed` position and the button is `absolute` with `top:0;right:0;`. But when the element is displayed (as shown in the snippet), the styling for the button changes to `"font-size: 12px; font-family: tahoma; right: 0px; color: rgb(85, 85, 85); visibility: visible;"`, removing the original absolute. If I manually add it into it using the inspect element, it goes to the right as intended. But why does it not show in the first place?

```js
adh('test', 320, 100);

function adh(dfp, len, hgt) {
  var adhBase = document.createElement('div');
  adhBase.id = dfp;
  if (false) {
    // is there mobile horizon???
  } else {
    adhBase.style = "z-index:9999;height:" + hgt + "px;position:fixed;bottom: 0;left: 50%;width:" + len + "px;transform: translateX(-50%);box-sizing: border-box;background-color:lightblue;";
  }
  document.body.appendChild(adhBase);

  // Close button
  var adhClose = document.createElement('button');
  adhClose.id = 'closeBtn';
  adhClose.style = 'font-size:12px;font-family:tahoma;position:absolute:top:0;right:0;border:1 px solid #ccc;color: #555;box-sizing:border-box:text-decoration:none;visibility:hidden';
  adhClose.innerHTML = 'close';
  document.getElementById(dfp).appendChild(adhClose);
  console.log('3');
  // function that closes the button
  document.getElementById('closeBtn').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
  });
  setTimeout(function() {
    adhClose.style.visibility = "visible"
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: `position:absolute:top:0;`, `box-sizing:border-box:text-decoration:none;`

Comment: Kevin B, I can see that you've typo'd that a bit, but are you just saying to remove the `right:0;` and that's it? Because if so, I've tried that.
https://jsfiddle.net/4qrh26ag/3/

Comment: i copied that from your code, there's colons where semi-colons should be.

Comment: Kevin B oh god now I just feel like an idiot *head smack* thanks

Comment: I suggest you to use domElement.class instead of domElement.style

Comment: iguypouf can you elaborate a bit as to why?

Comment: because its easier to maintain, easier to read, easier to animate, and will stay compatible if you add CSP on your application